# Install amarok, Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND, this code requires Qt 4.x

Tags: qt, cmake

I try to install **Amarok 2.8** music player from source in **CentOS7.0**.

After reading the README, I knew that Qt4.7(or later) is required. Then I installed the **QT5.3**(the path is ～/QT).

Followed the Amarok installation instructions,https://community.kde.org/Amarok/Development/Compiling
,

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=`kde4-config --prefix`
```

However,

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1368 (message):
  Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND, this code requires Qt 4.x
Call Stack (most recent call first):
```

I think there is way to tell the cmake where to find the QT.

Hope someone can solve this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

in CentOS, you can try:

yum install qt-devel

Answer (score 2):

CMake usually uses `qmake` to find and determine the Qt version, so make sure that is in your path.

However, you are answering your own question already:

> After reading the README, I knew that **Qt4.7**(or later) is required. Then I installed the **QT5.3**(the path is ～/QT).

The Amarok CMake script reminds you of this by telling you:

> this code requires Qt **4**.x

(*emphasis mine*)